# Canno't execute sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

Tags: apt, kali-linux, php

When I try to execute `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`:

It displays me this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in <module>
sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties /SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
self.reload_sourceslist()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/  SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 93, in get_sources
(self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Kali/kali-rolling
```

Comment: Did you need to install php?

Comment: Are you sure this repository is appropriate for your OS version?

Comment: You know that reminder we give out every time we notice someone using Kali as a desktop OS telling them not to do so because that's not what it's for? **That goes extra double special about using Kali as a server OS**. *Don't*.

Answer (score 1):

To install php on Kali Linux, open the terminal and type in:

```
sudo apt install php*
```

Then you should be able to use the latest version of php.

Comment: Good suggestion but it would have been nice to know what the heck OP was trying to achieve with that package.

Comment: Installing PHP on Kali linux seems... Unwise.

Answer (score 0):

The installation command of PHP on your OS without the *

`sudo apt install php`

The command will install the apache2 package if you don't have any webserver running yet.